# Schemas, Xml and java

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xsd

This week i was asked to change the old msgs communication system to XML msgs as i understood i have to make a xml schema that need have the stuct of the data to use to validate xml files.

The problem is i don't have any idea how. Can anyone show a good guide how to do this process of creating the schema and using it to validate the xmls in java ?

thx for ur time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use a web service. Apache CXF (cxf.apache.org) supports JMS and soap transports, and there are plenty of tutorials on the site.

If for some reason you must do this from scratch, you might want to look at xmlbeans. Tutorials there will show you a schema and how to generate java code from it.

Comment: oh gosh i have no ideia what is Apache CXF and JMS. :O

Comment: So, have a look. CXF is an open source web service framework/toolkit. JMS is a standard for Java reliable messaging.

Comment: oh gosh i have no ideia what is Apache CXF and JMS. :O 
I want a lib to generate XML that i will send via xmpp msgs and validate the xml using a xml-schema nothing to much complex because i'm running this app on android... sry i got away and when finish the write cant edited :P

Comment: i will have a look at this apache CXF but i dont think i have a chance using web services on android...

Comment: @Win you didn't tag 'android'. I'm sure you can do a web service client on Android. But you might do better with a dead-simple REST client based on commons-httpclient instead of trying to run all of CXF.